# Oracle Apex, documentation for apex_app_builder_api package, or setting null in interactive reports dynamically

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on an existing apex application which uses the apex_app_builder_api package to create and maintain apex pages, and has created hundreds of reports which I am supporting.
There is almost no documentation in Oracle for this package.

The specific issue I am investigating now is setting the null attribute when creating interactive reports using this package. Its set to display - the user would like it to be blank when null.

So please reply if you:

- Can point me to document on the apex_app_builder_api, specifically the create_ir_page function and the p_columns parameter.
- Know how to set a null attribute dynamically for Interactive Reports in Apex.

Thanks in advance,
Conor

Comment: There is no public documentation for this package because its use is not supported.  However, hopefully there may be someone on here who knows it and can help you.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I wouldn't have chosen to use it myself but since its in place I'd like to find out anything I can about it.

Comment: I was able to update the allow_save_rpt_public field in WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEETS directory to sort the issue but I'll leave the call open in case anyone has documentation on apex_app_builder_api.